# Ghost Haunting the Election Page

Tags: bug, moderators, moderator-election

Well, obviously Jeremy Banks isn't running for moderator this time :D

[image]

Why am I seeing this? Is this a bug? An illustration?

Comment: Ghost? where???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because he [put in a nomination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26909204#26909204) as an experiment/joke* then withdrew.

That Jeremy Banks, what a card!

On a more useful note: All candidates who withdraw during the primaries will appear that way (above their avatar it will identify the time that they withdrew). As bluefeet states in comments below Mr. Banks' nomination has now been deleted entirely, but other withdrawn candidates will appear in this way.

<sub>* Or mistake. Maybe he just forgot.</sub>

Comment: We've deleted his nomination, it should no longer appear.

Comment: @bluefeet Confirmed it no longer appears.

Comment: Clarification - this will appear if they delete in the primary phase.

Comment: *"Maybe he just forgot"* This is it. I forgot that I had already been elected, but was quickly reminded when I saw *a diamond on a nomination post (!!! ??? ...)*, and deleted it.

Comment: @Jeremy You know, if you get elected twice the diamond turns into a U+1F4A9.